# Proving an identity involving Fourier coefficient

Tags: functional-analysis, proof-verification, fourier-analysis

> If $f \sim \sum A_n e^{inx}$ and $g \sim \sum a_n e^{inx}$ and $f,g$ are continuous $2\pi$ periodic functions, show that
>   $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) \overline{g(t)} dt = \sum_{-\infty}^\infty A_n \overline{a_n}$$

I cannot find any mistake in my proof but I am having an extra constant. Here is what I have:

By Parseval identity, we have
\begin{align}
    \|f\|_{L^2} = \sqrt{2\pi} \left(\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f^2(t) dt\right)^\frac{1}{2} =\sqrt{2\pi}  \sqrt{\sum |a_n|^2} = \sqrt{2\pi} \| (\cdots,a_0,a_1,\cdots)\|_{l^2}
\end{align}
So a natural isometry would be
\begin{align}
\phi:&L^2 \to l^2\\
    &f \to \sqrt{2\pi} ( \cdots, a_0,a_1,\cdots)
\end{align}

And this is indeed an isometry since
\begin{align}
    \|f\|_{L^2} = \sqrt{2\pi} \| (\cdots,a_0,a_1,\cdot)\|_{L^2} = \sqrt{ \sum 2\pi a_n^2} = \|\phi(f)\|_{l^2} 
\end{align}

As a result,
\begin{align}
\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(t) \overline{g(t)} dt = \langle f(t),g(t)\rangle_{L^2} = \langle \phi(f),\phi(g)\rangle_{l^2} = 2\pi \sum A_n \overline{a_n}
\end{align}

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: the constants are boring. all I know is that if $f$ is $1$ periodic and $L^2([0,1])$  then (in $L^2([0,1])$ :  $f(x) = \sum_n c_n e^{2 i \pi n x}$ with $c_n = \int_0^1 f(x) e^{-2 i \pi n x} dx$ (no constants), and hence $\int_0^1 |f(x)|^2 dx =  \sum_n |c_n|^2$. can you solve from this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

None of the cross terms survive in the following:
\begin{align}
     \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(t)\overline{g(t)}dt & = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sum_{n=\infty}^{\infty}A_n e^{int}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\overline{a_n}e^{-int}dt \\
   & =\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}A_n\overline{a_n}\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{int}e^{-int}dt \\
   & = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}A_n \overline{a_n}.
\end{align}
The above is justified for all $f,g\in L^2$. This includes your functions $f$, $g$, which are assumed to be continuous on $[-\pi,\pi]$. I vote for your answer being correct.